# How to Create This Route in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, routes

I want to create a route something like:

```
http://images.example.com/[models]/[sizes]_[filename].[extension]
```

[models] = (blog|event|user) 
[sizes] = (t|s|l|o) 
[filename] = example 
[extension] = (png|gif|jpg)

How do I create the route for this? I've tried the following w/ no success:

```
Router::connect('/:model/:size\_:filename.:extension', 
array('controller' => 'images', 'action' => 'server'),array( 
                'model'=>'(blog|event|users)+', 
                'size'=>'(t|m|l|o)', 
                'filename'=>'\w+', 
                'extension'=>'.(gif|png|jpg)', 
                ));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll be able to do what you want through a custom route class (if you're using CakePHP 1.3+).

Check out this [blog post](http://mark-story.com/posts/view/using-custom-route-classes-in-cakephp) for more information.

Comment: there's no need of a custom router class here.

Answer (score 0):

should be like this:

```
Router::connect('/:model/:size_:filename.:extension', 
array('controller' => 'images', 'action' => 'server'),array( 
                'model'=>'(blog|event|users)', 
                'size'=>'(t|m|l|o)', 
                'filename'=>'\w+', 
                'extension'=>'(gif|png|jpg)', 
                ));
```